# Сомнительный случай

Tags: пунктуация

Как написать это предложение? Со скобками или тире?

Марина ответила: "У вас есть время до десяти часов. Если не оплатите — вернём деньги" **— при этом, ничего не написав до этого времени.**

Comment: Запятой после "при этом" нет. В словах автора деепричастный оборот нельзя отрывать от сказуемого, это грамматическая ошибка, поэтому никакое тире или скобки не помогут.

Comment: Нужно как-то обосновать появление слов "при этом". Например: Марина ответила: "...". Она сразу перешла к угрозам, не ответив при этом не на одно наше обращение

Answer (score 3):

Конструкция тяжеловата. Лучше так:

"У вас есть время до десяти часов. Если не оплатите — вернём деньги", —  ответила Марина после довольно долгого молчания".

Или: "У вас есть время до десяти часов. Если не оплатите — вернём деньги", —  ответила Марина, до этого момента не написавшая ни слова".